# anyone converting an onnx to coreml or pytorch to coreml

Tags: coremltools, onnx-coreml

Does anyone convert an onnx to coreml or pytorch to coreml successfully recently? Especially the case where pytorch model is not classifier but a feature extractor.

I tried a lot of ways to do that. But all of them failed either because of non-compatibility or other reasons. I'm desperate for somebody's saving me out of this dilemma.

I tried the latest version of coremltools but get an error shown below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drlx8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBZdN.png)
This is the complete error.
TypeError: Input strides has type <class 'coremltools.converters.mil.mil.types.type_tensor.tensor..tensor'> not compatible with expected type IntTensorInputType